# Find the roots of the given equation : $2^{x+2}.3^{\frac{3x}{x-1}} =9$ - Logarithm problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, quadratics

Find the roots of the given equation :

$2^{x+2}.3^{\frac{3x}{x-1}} =9$

My working :

Taking log on both sides we get : $$\log (2^{x+2}.3^{\frac{3x}{x-1}}) =\log 3^2  \Rightarrow (x+2)(\log2) + \frac{3x}{x-1}\log 3 = 2\log 3$$

Now how to proceed further in this problem... please suggest thanks....

Answer (score 2):

As $\log_aa=1$ and $\log_a(a^m)=m\log_aa=m$

taking logarithm wrt $3,$

$$(x+2)\log_32+\frac{3x}{x-1}=2$$

$$\implies(x+2)\log_32=2-\frac{3x}{x-1}=-\frac{x+2}{x-1}$$

$$\implies (x+2)\left(\log_32+\frac1{x+1}\right)=0$$

We know if $a\cdot b\cdot c\cdots=0;$  at least one of $a,b,c,\cdots$ is zero

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$2^{x+2}\cdot3^{\frac{3x}{x-1}}=3^2\iff 2^{x+2}=3^{2-\frac{3x}{x-1}}=3^{-\frac{x+2}{x-1}}\iff \begin{cases}x+2=0\\{}\\x-1=-\log_23\end{cases} \;\;(\text{why?)}$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $x-1$?

Comment: Yes it does, @chubakueno. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

we could argue that 9 is divisible by 3 and not 2
so wlog

$\large2^{x+2}3^{\frac{3x}{x-1}}=9$

$2^{x+2}$ should be one,so $x=-2$
also

$ \large 3^{\frac{3x}{x-1}}=3^2$

${\frac{3x}{x-1}}=2\implies x=-2$

Comment: The problem does not assume we are using integers

Answer (score -1):

Think of something to multiply the entire equation by that will remove any $x$'s from the denominator.